# Convert existing Raspbian image to NOOBS image?

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-stretch, noobs, berryboot

I currently have an SD card with a Raspbian (Stretch) install, a whole bunch of files, an OpenVPN server, etc. However, I would like to run Kali Linux and LibreELEC on it as well. Is there any way I can convert the existing Raspbian install to a NOOBS/BerryBoot/PINN image, or do I have to re-install everything from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PINN/NOOBS the image is basically a standard image, just installed on different partitions. With changes to `etc/fstab` and `cmdline.txt` to match actual partitions it could be converted (it would obviously need to be shrunk to fit).

Exactly WHY anyone would want to do this eludes me. SD cards are cheap and 2 small cards are probably cheaper than 1 large card.

If I was to do this I would start with a PINN image, then replace the Raspbian root partition (first copying `etc/fstab`). (I wouldn't even contemplate NOOBS.)

BerryBoot has lots of other dependencies, so while it MAY be possible it is infeasible.